# different CPU speed after motherboard replacment

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard

my CPU speed was 2.4 but now it became 2.00 GHz, my laptop is Acer Aspire 4736z, I replaced my motherboard with a different motherboard (all of them are design for the same laptop).

this laptop has 4 differnt CPUs mine was the highest 2.4, but it runes at 2.00. if any one knows how to get my CPU speed back.

the CPU heat is very low at 14 to 19 degrees.

Comment: Have you made sure your BIOS configuratin is exactly the same as it was and your using the current BIOS revision for the new board?  Your laptop does not have 4 different CPUs, it has 4 Cores, there is a huge different.  I also wonder what CPU you have exactly.  Please update your question to clarify these points.

Comment: @Ramhound OP probably meant that this laptop series featured 4 different CPU models.

Comment: @gronostaj - Which is the reason I want him to clarify his question.

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop doesn't run at 2.4 GHz but at 2GHz, your CPU might have been running in Turbo when you read those 2.4GHz. Modern CPUs can overclock a core when other cores aren't in use all that much.

Source: http://www.engadget.com/products/acer/aspire/4736z/specs/